# ¿Cómo descomprimir un archivo ZIP dentro de otro ZIP con PHP?

Tags: php, zip

comunidad!
Espero me puedan ayudar, Mediante PHP tengo que hacer la carga de un archivo zip el cual contiene otro archivo zip, dentro del segundo zip contiene los archivos, con los cuales trabajaré. Cabe mencionar que el primer zip lo sube el usuario a raíz de esa carga quisiera que fuera en automático la segunda extracción.

Mi código ya descomprime el primer zip, me encuentro perdido en el segundo zip.
[image: Es el código que hace la extracción del ZIP 1]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí tienes un ejemplo completo en PHP que descomprime un archivo ZIP principal que contiene múltiples archivos ZIP internos. El código extrae el contenido de cada archivo ZIP interno a un directorio temporal y luego mueve los archivos a un directorio de destino:

```php
<?php

function descomprimirZipDentroDeZip($archivoZipPrincipal, $directorioDestino)
{
    // Crear un objeto ZipArchive para el archivo ZIP principal
    $zipPrincipal = new ZipArchive;
    if ($zipPrincipal->open($archivoZipPrincipal) === TRUE) {
        // Iterar sobre los archivos internos del ZIP principal
        for ($i = 0; $i < $zipPrincipal->numFiles; $i++) {
            $nombreArchivo = $zipPrincipal->getNameIndex($i);

            // Verificar si el archivo es un ZIP
            if (pathinfo($nombreArchivo, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'zip') {
                // Crear un objeto ZipArchive para el archivo ZIP interno
                $zipInterno = new ZipArchive;
                if ($zipInterno->open('zip://' . $archivoZipPrincipal . '#' . $nombreArchivo) === TRUE) {
                    // Extraer el contenido del ZIP interno a un directorio temporal
                    $tempDir = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'zip_temp');
                    unlink($tempDir);
                    mkdir($tempDir);
                    $zipInterno->extractTo($tempDir);
                    $zipInterno->close();

                    // Extraer el contenido del ZIP principal al directorio de destino
                    $zipPrincipal->extractTo($directorioDestino);

                    // Mover los archivos del ZIP interno al directorio de destino
                    moverContenido($tempDir, $directorioDestino);

                    // Eliminar el directorio temporal
                    eliminarDirectorioTemporal($tempDir);

                    echo 'Descompresión exitosa para ' . $nombreArchivo . '<br>';
                } else {
                    echo 'No se pudo abrir el archivo ZIP interno: ' . $nombreArchivo . '<br>';
                }
            }
        }

        // Cerrar el archivo ZIP principal
        $zipPrincipal->close();
    } else {
        echo 'No se pudo abrir el archivo ZIP principal.';
    }
}

function moverContenido($directorioOrigen, $directorioDestino)
{
    $archivos = glob($directorioOrigen . '/*');
    foreach ($archivos as $archivo) {
        if (is_file($archivo)) {
            $nombreArchivo = pathinfo($archivo, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
            rename($archivo, $directorioDestino . '/' . $nombreArchivo);
        }
    }
}

function eliminarDirectorioTemporal($directorio)
{
    $archivos = glob($directorio . '/*');
    foreach ($archivos as $archivo) {
        if (is_file($archivo)) {
            unlink($archivo);
        }
    }
    rmdir($directorio);
}

// Uso de la función
$archivoZipPrincipal = 'ruta/archivo_principal.zip';
$directorioDestino = 'ruta/destino';

descomprimirZipDentroDeZip($archivoZipPrincipal, $directorioDestino);

?>
```

Recuerda ajustar las rutas del archivo ZIP principal y del directorio de destino según tus necesidades. Este código imprimirá mensajes en el navegador indicando el éxito o fallo de la descompresión de cada archivo ZIP interno.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda. Del primer zip si obtengo el nombre del archivo ya que lo sube el usuario a un <input>, del segundo lo pone en una ruta de ahí es donde no se como obtener el nombre ya que puede tener varios zip´s

Comment: entonces son varios zips?

Comment: Son conjuntos de un ZIP salen uno varios ZIP´s

Comment: He editado la respuesta y este código deberia ayudarte